# Deserialization of corrupt XML hangs up XmlReader

Tags: c#, xml, deserialization, xmlserializer, catel

Accidently, I stumpled across a misformatted XML file having this content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<MainModel xmlns:ctl="http://schemas.catelproject.com" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" ctl:graphid="1">
  <DataId>123</DataId>
  <DataName>Main Data Name</DataName>
  <DataCollection ctl:graphid="2">
    <SubModel ctl:graphid="3" xmlns:d0p0="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/CatelSpoiledDerialization.Models" i:type="d0p0:SubModel">
      <SubId>200</
```

As the XML code shows, my example project (https://github.com/thoblerone/CatelSpoiledDerialization) is using the Catel framework, but deep debugging points towards a possible issue in System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlReader

The code to deserialize is pretty straght forward

```
var iXmlSer = SerializationFactory.GetXmlSerializer();
using var fileStream = File.Open(res.FileName, FileMode.Open);

var myData = iXmlSer.Deserialize<MainModel>(fileStream);
```

Yet, the call to Deserialize will never finish. Stepping through with the debugger, I see that the underlying .net XmlReader is calling MoveToContent while pointing to defective element (SubId) but the call will never succeed nor does it throw an exception, which I would gladly accept.

Am I missing come xml reader configuration that would check file conformity before tryinto to read the stuff?

Comment: Cannot reproduce https://dotnetfiddle.net/DQ24kX An exception is thrown once the end of the file is reached, and `MoveToContent` returns successfully.

Comment: The xml library does not work with corrupt xml.  Where did you get the corrupt xml? You need to fix the code that got the bad xml.  Looks like a connection closed before you got all the data.

Comment: @Chalieface The problem may not occur in your fiddle, but it can be reproduced using the complete code. Maybe my thoughts while debugging were wrong. For me stepping through is possible until within the function System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlSerializableReader.MoveToContent which then calls  InnerReader.MoveToContent, which hangs, with InnerReader being a XmlSerializer. Maybe Catel is putting it in a different state that does not throw.

Comment: @jdweng As said, I "stumbled" across the real file in question, when processing several thousands of data files from a real time application that were collected over the last several months with the application currently being devoloped. There is no hint what may have happened as the file before and after are fine and in expected chronologial order.

Comment: OK a [mcve] is needed, otherwise this question is not answerable

Comment: @ThomasB - `XmlReader` will not hang in the event of truncated XML, it will properly throw an exception.  But higher-level code *might* hang e.g. if is swallowing exceptions or working directly with the `XmlReader` by e.g. implementing `IXmlSerializable`.  Can you share a [mcve]?  It looks like that XML was generated by the data contract serializer for a data model that includes polymorphic subtypes, so we would need to see a (simplified, but possibly polymorphic) data model that reproduces the problem.